# How would a separate GUI class communicate with logic classes?

Tags: java, user-interface, model-view-controller

I am trying to design a tic tac toe game that has multiple classes. One class is the GUI class that shows 9 buttons to represent the 9 areas of a tic tac toe board. Another class is my driver class that sets up the game. The other classes are the logic behind the game (board, moves). However, I am not sure how to let the GUI class and logic classes interact with each other.

I do not want the GUI class to have direct access to the board, but I do not know how else I am supposed to relay information back and forth. For example, if I hit a button, the text of the button should be updated to reflect the mark (either an X or an O), but I do not know what mark to change the text to without checking whose turn it is and that information is located in the Board class. A button press should also let the Board know what spaces are available and that a player turn has been conducted.

I am trying to have the Board class have accessor methods so the GUI can figure out how to properly update itself, but I am completely loss as to how I would call such methods in the GUI class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the concepts behind [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). At some point, the components are going to have to interact with each other, because they have to pass information between them. The point is to *decouple the interaction from the implementation of the result*.

In other words, the view should have some standard interface that lets the model/controller notify it it needs updating, and the model/controller should have some standard interface that the view uses to inform it of user input, but neither should care how the other goes about handling those events. In theory, a perfect MVC implementation would let you switch out any one of the components for a completely different implementation as long as it stuck to the same interface and everything would work exactly as expected.

In your case, I would design things such that there is a game-engine class which has a method such as this:

```
int makeMove(row, column)
```

Where `row` and `column` are coordinates on the board, and the returned `int` represents the player (X = 0, O = 1 or similar. You could even use an `enum` to be more explicit``) whose turn it was, so that the GUI can update the appropriate square with that player's icon.

The game engine would then expect the view to have at least these two methods:

```
void setPlayerTurn(int player)
```

Which tells the GUI that it should update the display on whose turn it is (same `player` as above)

```
void setPlayerWon(int player, rows, columns)
```

Which tells the GUI that a player was victorious, and that it should update the three squares identified with `rows` and `columns` as being the ones that made a player win, and `player` is the same player number as above so that it can display the appropriate status message.

The game logic, including tracking the state of the board and whose turn it is can then all be self contained inside the game class, and all the GUI is doing is relaying information from the user to the game, and from the game to the user. You could theoretically swap out either component with a completely different implementation that adhered to those interfaces and still have the game play as expected.

So, the GUI (view) winds up with a reference to the Game Logic (model), and vise-versa. But they're only interacting with each other through a very narrow and generalized interface. Neither really knows or cares what the other does with the information passed through that interface.

Note that in this simplified example I've combined the controller with the view, which is a pretty common thing to do when you're designing a single-purpose GUI. Essentially, the GUI is designed such that it is only ever going to be useful as a Tic Tac Toe board, but it expects you to provide your own set of rules (model).

Having said that, you could see how it wouldn't take much more to decouple these even further by making the GUI simply expose methods that let you set the state (text and icon) of an arbitrary square on a grid, and display a status message. It would expect to be given a controller that provided a method to notify what square on the grid a user interacted with. The controller would then provide the glue to interface between that generic 'grid with status message' view and the game logic model, which expects the interface I described above.

In this case, the GUI (view) gets a reference to the Controller and vise-versa, and then the Controller gets a reference to the Game Logic (model) and vise-versa.

Comment: Thank you! This certainly makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can import the logic class and then create an instance of that class in your GUI, then you have access to all the methods in that class.

The code it would look like this

```
import Logicclassname
public guiclass{
Logicclassname logic=new logicclassname();
}

public void updatefield(){
logic.functiontoexecute();
/* rest of code*/
}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid having my GUI class have an instance of the the Board class. I think if I do that, then the GUI isn't really separate from the logic. The way my teacher phrased it was like so "Note that the GUI will need to keep its display up-to-date with the current board position, but you do not want the board itself to be part of the GUI. What you can do is make sure that the methods supplied by the board permit the GUI to query the board for the information it needs in order to update the display."

Comment: Without an instance you can't access the methods as far as I know, but if you only want the board to be able to access the methods it actually need, make those public, the rest private.

Comment: The way my teacher phrased it makes me believe that my GUI should not have an instance of the Board class, but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can make them static fields and access them through ClassType.getVariable()

for example:

```
public class Board
{
    private static char currentPlayer = 'X';

    public static char getCurrentPlayer()
    {
        return currentPlayer;
    }
}
```

and in your GUI class you use `Board.getCurrentPlayer();`